# golden dict problem

Tags: 13.04, goldendict

I have just install 'goldendict' on my ubuntu 13.04 and when I try to run it a massage apears :

```
GoldenDict has crashed with an unexpected exception

Exception: Config::exMalformedConfigFile
Message: The configuration file is malformed

Backtrace:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ef76) [0x7f874ddf3f76]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5efa3) [0x7f874ddf3fa3]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5f1de) [0x7f874ddf41de]
  goldendict(Config::load()+0xa25) [0x484075]
  goldendict(main+0x48a) [0x4584aa]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f874d4d3ea5]
  goldendict() [0x459d81]
```

can any body help me dealing with this problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear enough. Identify the config file, either temporary move it to another location or edit it. I don't have 13.04, but based on my version, goldendict creates a directory in the home folder called `.goldendict`. Try moving it temporarily to another location. Open a terminal and type

```
mv .goldendict .goldendict-backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on /usr/share/apps/goldendict/ sub-folders, especially if you have manually unpacked any dictionary there.